# Is there a way to shoot with selective color in Nikon d5300?

Tags: nikon, color-filters

I see shots from some photographers that take shots with one color in it (red for example). Is there a custom setting that makes that happen for us? How should I achieve this result without using post-processing apps?

[image: http://whiteknightpress.com/selective-color-setting-with-the-nikon-coolpix-p510/]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the Manual

**01. Rotate the mode dial to EFFECTS.**
[image]

**02. Rotate the command dial until Selective Color option appears in the monitor.**
[image]

**03. Rotate the live view switch. The view through the lens will be displayed in the monitor.**
[image]

**04. Press OK to display Selective Color options.**
[image]

**05. Select a color.**
Frame an object in the white square in the center of the display and press the multi selector up to choose the color of the object as one that will remain in the final image.
[image]

**06. Choose the color range.**

Press the multi selector up or down to increase or decrease the range of similar hues that will be included in the final image. Choose from values between 1 and 7; note that higher values may include hues from other colors.
[image]

**07. Select additional colors.**

To select additional colors, rotate the command dial to highlight another of the three color boxes at the top of the display and repeat Steps 3 and 4 to select another color. Repeat for a third color if desired.

To deselect the highlighted color, press Delete (To remove all colors, press and hold Delete. A confirmation dialog will be displayed; select Yes).
[image]

**08. Press OK to return to live view.**

During shooting, only objects of the selected hues will be recorded in color; all others will be recorded in black-and-white.

To exit live view, rotate the live view switch. The selected settings will continue in effect and will apply to photographs taken using the viewfinder.